# Splash screen in Java maven project

Tags: java, maven, splash-screen

I am trying to get a splash screen in my project. In eclipses I have found a solution to put 
VM arguments `-splash:src/main/resources/images/cover.png` But where do i put this arguments while running a project through maven command line.

Comment: As Maven is primarily a build / project tool and not exactly for running projects you need to be more specific. Do you think of test runs of your application? Or the start of Maven itself? Applications that are started by `exec:java`? Applications/Jars generated by Maven?

Comment: Yes application are started by exec:java by in java If you give VM option as "-splash:src/main/resources/images/cover.png" then it shows a splash screen But I am not able to to do it when i am using mvn command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec:java` runs the application in the same Java process as Maven so a JVM splash screen is not possible.

If you use `exec:exec` you can start a separate Java process and provide arguments to this in the plugin configuration, e.g.:

```
<build><plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-splash:src/main/resources/images/cover.png</argument>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath />
            <argument>com.company.MainClass</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins></build>
```

- [Plugin Documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html)
- [Example](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use the maven-jar-plugin to add the splash screen to your manifest:

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifestEntries>
            <SplashScreen-Image>images/cover.png</SplashScreen-Image>
          </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```